# What does "itadakimashite" do in this case?

Tags: meaning

So on the shinkansen, the announcer says something along the lines of:

> Kyou mo JR wo goriyou itadakimashite, makotoni arigatou gozaimasu.

What does *itadakimashite* do in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't くださいまして{kudasaimashite}? The Tokaido / Sanyo Shinkansen (Tokyo-Osaka / Osaka-Hakata) announcment is "今日{きょう}も、東海道{とうかいどう}／山陽{さんよう} 新幹線{しんかんせん}をご利用{りよう} ***くださいまして***、誠{まこと}にありがとうございました。..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

いただきまして is just the 〜て form of いただきます.  It is the more polite version of いただいて (the 〜て form of いただく).

But the real issue here is the form `ご＋[noun of する verb]＋いただく`.  This is polite speech ([謙譲語]{けん・じょう・ご}) used to humble yourself toward someone "higher up" to (more or less) say that they did something favourable/beneficial to you (compare/contrast with `ご＋[noun of する verb]＋くださる`); in this case, the JR company is humbling themselves toward the passengers as "higher ups", thanking them for using JR.

Here's the verb conjugation

> 利用する (make use of)　→　ご利用いただく (humbly receive your making use of)

So presumably you know that the whole phrase means

> We sincerely thank you for using JR today (too).

Answer (score 0):

In the honorific language, used by business owners,shopkeepers, etc when talking to their customers and in this case the JR company to their customers ie the passengers, some basic verbs are changed:

"suru" becomes "itasu" (to do)
"morau" becomes "itadaku" (to receive)

"goriyou" means literally "use", the go- part is also used as an honorific.

"goriyou itadaku" is a common collocation used by companies and service providers when addressing their customers and it roughly means "to make use of (service)"

Shinkansen goriyou itadakimashite arigatou gozaimasu 
"Thank you for using the shinkansen"